# How to fix ' AttributeError: module 'discord.channel' has no attribute 'DMChannel' ' Python3.6

Tags: bots, python-3.6, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

I was creating a discord bot but there was error.
in windows (local pc) there wasn't any error about 'discord.channel' has no attribute 'DMChannel'
but when i wanted launch bot at Ubuntu it throw me this error

what i have tried:
Installed: python 3.5.3 , 3.5.7 , 3.5.0 , 3.6.0 , 3.6.5 , 3.6.6 , 3.7.0 
my bot's file name DC.py so error couldnt be due to name (if it was discord.py it could be)

```
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.author.bot is True:
            return
        if type(message.channel) is discord.channel.DMChannel:
            message.content = f"{self.command_prefix}help"
        await self.process_commands(message)
```

Prolem at

```
 if type(message.channel) is discord.channel.DMChannel:
```

I tried to delete this part of code but it run to

```
embed.timestamp = message.created_at
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english I'm russian

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  (`print(discord.__version__)`)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Fixed it. 
it was normal discord.py, not rewrite 
rewrite version fixed it